# Virtualization: RAID the Host OS or VM Storage?

Tags: virtualization, performance, raid

If I only had 1 pair of 15,000 RPM SAS drives in RAID 0 to dedicate to a VM box, would it be best to

a) put the HOST OS on the raid drives and put the VM's on a single SATA 10,000 RPM drive

b) put the VM's on the raid drives and the OS on the SATA 10k drive.

c) Put both the OS and the VM's on the SAS RAID and forget about the SATA 10k.

If so, why?

Not asking for benchmarks here, just some logic of what would theoretically be best on a  small-scale low-traffic VM box.

Comment: I would sell all of the 15K and 10K drives and buy one or more Intel (or better) SSDs.

Answer (score 5):

All on the 15k SAS drives, but in RAID-1 not RAID-0.  The host shouldn't be doing anything much, so won't use it's disk IO much, while the guests doing the work will need more IO, and a single drive isn't much use for anything.

Comment: Thanks! Why RAID-1 and not RAID-0 though? If I don't really need 100% uptime and I have automated image backups, can't I afford RAID-0?

Comment: If your data is really that unimportant to you that you're willing to wipe out the whole thing every time you lose a disk, go nuts.  I would consider the use of RAID-0 for anything more than a large scale cache to be bordering on negligence, though.  Big disks are cheap, if you need the space, and the testing I've done doesn't show all that much of a performance benefit.

Comment: +1 for RAID-1. It's a total waste of time rebuilding the system everytime a disk dies.

Comment: you could put all 3 drives on a ZFS and then get to make use of all of them ...

Comment: Yes, because ZFS magically manages to provide infinite redundancy without any storage or performance overhead...

Comment: This box is just hosting non-mission-critical virtual machines for testing purposes only (no critical data). They can be restored within the hour from an image backup if and when one of the 2 drives fails. Considering all that, the 2x performance gain in disk writes of striping makes a helluva lot more sense than a fixation with redundancy

Comment: You won't get twice the performance out of a 2-disk RAID-0.  1.5x maybe, if you're doing mostly large contiguous transfers.

Comment: A year and a half later and this host is churning along with several VM's. The testing performance is top notch and all the time saved from the superior performance of RAID-0 will be well worth the 2 hours of downtime if and when a drive fails.

Answer (score 2):

I would:

- Put the OS on the RAID-0 15k drives
- Distribute *some* virtual disks on the 15k drives
- Distribute *other* virtual disks on the 10k drive

I/O is truly the enemy of virtualization, so using as many spindles as possible is the win here.

If you can segregate your usage in any meaningful way (i.e. VMs "A" and "B" usually access the disks concurrently) then use that knowledge to intelligently choose which virtual disks to place on each drive.

Comment: Interesting answer. Clearly distributing among the scare I/O is the major thing to go for here. Makes me wonder whether a VM on a separate 7200RPM single drive would beat out one on a 15K RAID volume shared with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

if space allows it put everything on mirrored sas drives - giving you security and io.